# the meaning of this sentence including 'otherwise'

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

I was reading a document and the meaning of this sentence is quite confusing to me.

It says:
If Dave doesn't request Amy's account information within 7 days, or otherwise require us(A&B corporation) to keep that information for longer, it will be removed.

After the comma, does it mean that they will also remove the information if Dave doesn't require them to keep Amy's information for longer (more than 7 days)?

I understood that they will remove the information

1. If Dave doesn't request the information within 7 days.
2. If Dave doesn't require them to keep the information for longer.(perhaps more than 7days)

Is that correct? It's quite strange to interpret that they will remove the information if Dave requires them to keep that information for longer.

Comment: The company may still consider themselves *obliged* to keep the account information because of something Dave tells them, even if he doesn't *explicitly* tell them to do this. For example, he might just be telling the company that Amy has died, so they should stop billing her for something. Maybe the company knows that in such circumstances they're legally obliged to keep certain account information for some reason, even though Dave himself hasn't thought about anything like that.

Comment: I believe you will find that it must be a formal request. It is law that Data must be stored for the shortest time possible. https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/law-topic/data-protection Therefore "Somewhere there will be a reference of how to do this"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**If he doesn't request his account information within 7 days, or otherwise require us to keep that information for longer, it will be removed.**

Q. After the comma, does it mean that they will also remove the information if he doesn't require them to keep that information for longer (more than 7 days)?

---

I have seen this statement several times, I am sure it is Legal jargon. That is why it sounds confusing.

**It means that the information will be removed after 7 days.** Unless the owner of the account requests that they do not remove it. Somewhere there will be a reference of how to do this in the small print, it may not be on the document (or screen), it may be in the original terms and conditions document.

---

**otherwise;** adverb; (**NOT INCLUDING**); except for what has just been referred to:

**If he doesn't request his account information within 7 days it will be removed , NOT INCLUDING, if he requires us to keep that information for longer.**

Ref CED [Otherwise](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/otherwise)

Answer (score 1):

If he doesn't request the account information within seven days, **or show in some other way** that he needs us to keep the information for longer, it will be removed.

Cambridge Dictionary (second definition):

> differently, or in another way: *Protestors were executed, jailed or otherwise persecuted.*

Comment: Reference? you may or may not remember me being chastised for that a couple of times in my early days.

Comment: OK, if you don't believe me I have supplied one.

Comment: It is not a matter of belief, it is a matter of etiquette, and I believe from, past comments that you are aware of this.